# My File Upload Form Does Not Upload Non-Image Files. Why?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML file upload form that uploads files on my server using PHP. It uploads image files but other type of files such as mp3 or mp4 are not uploading. I can't figure out what's the problem.

Here is the code:

> HTML :

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" action="upload.php?ref=home" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="shout_media" class="hidden" name="media" type="file" />
</form>
```

> PHP :

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['ref'])) {

   if((isset($_FILES['media']))&&(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['media']['tmp_name']))) {

      $name = $_FILES['media']['name'];

      $tmpname = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];

      $size = $_FILES['media']['size'];

      $i = strrpos($name,".");

      if (!$i) { return ""; }

      $l = strlen($name) - $i;

      $xt = substr($name,$i+1,$l);

      $ext = strtolower($xt);

      if(preg_match("/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|mp4)/",$ext)) {

          if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname,'photos/'.$name.'')) {

               echo 'Uploaded successfully!';

           }

      }

  }
```

I'm using jQuery and http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ Ajax Form Plugin to upload files without reloading the page.

> AJAX Form Plugin Code:

```
$("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
   success: function(responseText) {
      if(responseText.length>0) {
           $(".uploadStatus").text('Uploaded!');
  }
   }
}).submit();
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it? I need to allow my users to upload other type of files, most importantly MP3s and MP4s.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line

`if(preg_match("/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/",$ext)) {`

is filtering files by extension. Add additional extensions you want to allow to the list, like

`if(preg_match("/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|mp4)/",$ext)) {`

Just be aware that all files will be uploaded to the same folder, so even your mp3 files will be in photos folder. If you don't want that, you have to change path for `move_uploaded_file` based on the filetype.

Since you have updated your question, check `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` settings in php to see if your files are larger than the maximum allowed size

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you may also want to move it somewhere else: This code will also put your mp3 and mp4 files in the "photos" directory, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot to state that. I have added mp3,mp4 on my code but it isnt working. It shows that $_FILES['media'] is empty.

Comment: @Adil check `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` settings in php to see if your files are larger than the maximum allowed size